# Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\php\pear): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, wordpress

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\php\pear): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\wpcodeyad\index.php on line 10

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\wpcodeyad\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wpcodeyad\index.php on line 10

what i have to do pls help!

searched on the web but didnt find my solution.

Comment: Did you uinstall PEAR? Do you have a `C:\xampp\php\PEAR` folder?

Answer (score 0):

This error can appear when you're trying to require a Directory, you should specify the file you want to require inside the directory
Ex. C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).